# Remover espaços e caracteres especiais de uma string

Tags: android

Olá, no meu projeto tenho um `EditText` que recebe um valor digitado pelo usuário.

```
EditText etListName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etListName);
```

Esse valor é convertido em `String`

```
String stringEtListName = etListName.getText().toString();
```

Após converter, pego o valor `stringEtListName` e crio uma tabela no banco de dados, mas, se caso o usuário colocar algum carácter especial e/ou espaços, precisa ser removido, pois o banco de dados não aceita tabelas com os mesmos.
Como eu faço essas remoções?
**Observação:** Lembrando que não quero que remova a letra, quero que remova apenas o carácter especial ou espaço.
**Exemplo:**

```
-- Certo
Usuário digitou: Lista Teste ãôé
Converção para: ListaTesteaoe

--Errado
Usuário digitou: Lista Teste ãôé
Converção para: ListaTeste
```

Att.
**Giovani Rodrigo**

Answer (score 2):

Você pode a princípio resolver esse problema criando um método que recebe uma *string* como entrada e retorne a frase sem os caracteres com acentos. Primeiro você precisa usar o método [`normalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html) para normalizar sua *string* de entrada usando [formulários de normalização Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-23.html), logo depois usar o `replaceAll()` com uma expressão regular para substituir os caracteres especiais removendo caracteres não `ASCII`. Veja:

```
String value = removeAccent("Lista Teste ãôé");
```

**Saída**

```
Lista Teste aoe
```

Segue abaixo o método:

```
public String removeAccent(final String str) {
    String strNoAccent = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    strNoAccent = strNoAccent.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
    return strNoAccent;
}
```